# jQuery script not showing equation result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, var, equation

I am working on a script to calculate some stuff using multiple input. I have been copy-pasting my script because it has been working for 2 values calculations. For example:

```
        //Diameter Pitch
                $(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
  var valM = parseInt($('.dpModule').val());
  var valZ = parseInt($('.dpJumlahGigi').val());
          var sum = valZ*valM;
          $("input#resultDP").val(sum);
});
});
```

But now I am trying to add another variable Phi (3.14) but the calculation is not working

```
    //Circular Pitch
        $(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
  var valD = parseInt($('.cpPitchDiameter').val());
  var valT = parseInt($('.cpAot').val());
    var phi = parseInt($('3.14').val());
          var sum = phi*valD/valT;
          $("input#resultCP").val(sum);
});
});
```

The circular pitch script resulted with NaN, can anyone please fix my code? I am trying to make the following formula:

```
var sum = 3.14*valD/valT;
```

Much thanks in advance

Comment: `$('3.14')` doesn't make any sense.  You are trying to find a DOM element with "3.14" as the selector, and that's not going to be found.  Do you see the problem now?

Comment: FYI [Phi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) and [Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) are two very different numbers. The latter is also available as a JS constant `Math.PI`

Comment: @user2740650 yeah I noticed, for whatever reason that I dont understand, I fixed the error myself, I corrected some stuff in the script and now it works again. But now, on certain calculation, the keyup event wont work. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace: `var phi = parseInt($('3.14').val());` with `var phi = 3.14;`.

Your current code is trying to look for a '3.14'tag in your HTML so it returns "not a number" since that doesn't exist in the HTML.

Comment: Even better would be to use `Math.PI`